# changing a variable in completionblock

Tags: objective-c

Hello I am currently having issues bridging a variable in my completion block. I want to set `isPreviewPlaying` to **NO** in the completion block but I can't.

```
static void completionCallback (SystemSoundID  mySSID, void *myself) {


  AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (mySSID);
  AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(mySSID);

  CFRelease(myself); 
  UIButton *previewButton = (__bridge UIButton*)myself;
  [previewButton setTitle:@"Preview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  _isPreviewPlaying = NO // I want to do this, but I can't.
}

- (void)previewButtonPressed:(id)sender {
 if (_isPreviewPlaying) {
   _isPreviewPlaying = NO;
   NSLog(@"STOP");
   AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
 } else {
   NSString * selectedPreviewSound = [self.soundFile objectAtIndex: _soundFileIndex];
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: selectedPreviewSound], &soundID);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
   _isPreviewPlaying = YES;
   AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion(soundID, NULL, NULL, completionCallback, (__bridge_retained void *)sender);
   [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
}
```

Comment: the variable `_isPreviewPlaying` has to be declared as `__block BOOL _isPreviewPlaying`; then it should let you modify the variable from within the block

Comment: @DavidJirman I assume `_isPreviewPlaying` is an instance variable so `__block` is not required.  The fact that's it out-of-scope to a C-function is the crucial factor here.

Comment: @Droppy: true, thanks for correcting me ...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the class instance to the completion <strike>block</strike> function, as it's a C function, and that way you  can access properties and methods on the instance.

That is the intent of `myself` parameter I believe, however you are currently releasing it using `CFRelease()` for some reason I cannot fathom (I am assuming that `sender` is a button as `previewButtonPressed:` looks like a button event callback, and releasing it won't do it any favours; read *crash*).

Therefore I would suggest:

1. Remove the `CFRelease()` call.
2. Cast `myself` to whatever the class is:  `MyClass *myclass = (MyClass *)myself;`.
3. <strike>Call `myclass.previewPlaying = NO;` (assuming it's a property)</strike>.  Call `[myclass previewNotPlaying]` (see below).
4. Pass `self` instead of `sender` to `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion()`.

**EDIT** Having said that, I now see you are using the button instance to display information.  Instead of calling the property, above, call a method on the instance instead and make that method do the work:

```
- (void)previewNotPlaying
{
    // _previewButton is an IBOutlet to the button
    [_previewButton setTitle:@"Preview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _isPreviewPlaying = NO;
}
```

Comment: 4a. No need to use `(__bridge_retained)`  (or any other variation) when passing `self` as the last parameter to `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion`.

Comment: @rmaddy Agreed; I should have paid attention to the use of the button in the callback.  I have corrected that now, I believe.

Comment: @Droppy you have to bridge cast the class `(__bridge MyClass *)myself;`